# Form information suddenly gets blank Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, database, forms, laravel

I have a Web Form which the user fills up and submit. It has a validation on client side like

```
<input type="text" name="fname" required="required"/>
```

Also I have a validation in the backend like

```
$rules = array(
      'input_date'             => 'required',
      'plan_holder'            => 'required',
      'birth_date'             => 'required',
      'address'                => 'required',
      'postcode'               => 'required',
      'telephone'              => 'required',
      'funeral_type'           => 'required',
      'funeral_plan_type'      => 'required',
      'payment_option'         => 'required',
  );

  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

  if ($validator->fails())
  {
      return Redirect::to('form/create')->withErrors($validator);
  }
  else
  {
    // Some code to insert in database
  }
```

How ever some users reporting that after they click submit submit the form will successfully submit and there times that when I look in the database all the fields including the required is blank BUT some fields has data on it like.

```
$form->agent_id = Auth::user()->id;
```

For some reason that I don't know the input data is being cleared out. When I test it on my own it's ok and working fine. It's no happening all the time. Is there something that I can look into?

I am very confuse coz I did not put any codes or logic to clear out the data. Plus I have two validations already both client side and backend so require some fields but weird enough sometime all the input field saved is cleared out to empty

Comment: DId you get any error in laravel log file http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors ? also check developers console network tab

Comment: @GaneshGhalame Nope. I didn't see any error relative to this in logs. Also the user didn't see any errors either.

Comment: Does your controller code getting executed ? there you can have problem of validation just cross check once by adding log or checking network tab in browser

Comment: @GaneshGhalame Yes. The controller get's executed because the I have a field to record the ID of the login user who submit the form and it's saving fine. Problem is the input fields suddenly cleared out. Yeah still checking on it.

Comment: Just add `$validator->errors();` after ` $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);`, you will get error messages if any

Comment: @GaneshGhalame Yeah. problem is the issue i mentioned happens very very rare. Most of the time it works. Even if I repeatedly input the data and submit it. It might work without the issue, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: have you tried testing it with a space character " " ? No sure if laravel considers a space a character when validating.

Comment: I'll suggest you to log the inputs before validation and later you can evaluate which parameter is missing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping out but this is fixed already. Problem is that the users is updating the form without any value. I have an edit page and I didn't know that somethime they edit a record with no data then submit it. That's the cause of the problem not in the `form/create`